# Were is run time type information stored in java?

Tags: java, reflection

Java and all modern languages have the capability for reflection in which it can give all the information about class, methods, constructors etc. So I was wondering, where is all this information stored in memory?

I am working on a library where I need to add additional type information to it. But I can't find any link explaining it.

Can someone please point me to suitable resources.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see for example this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-codetoheap/ if you question about "Anatomy of a Java object in memory"

Comment: I do not completely get what you mean by `where does all this information stored in memory`, but you can attach additional runtime information to Classes and methods through [Annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/)

Comment: When you say “I need to add additional type information to it” you are very likely wrong. And asking the wrong question. Instead of “where is all this information stored in memory?” you should have asked “how can I add information to it?” and the answer is “you can’t”.  The runtime type information of Java classes is just reflecting the compile time type information or, in other words, conceptually immutable data describing invariant properties.

Answer (score 1):

Before Java 8: Run time type information stored in java in [Permanent Generation](https://www.google.pl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=Permanent%20Generation%20java), in Java 8 in [Metaspace](https://www.google.pl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Metaspace%20java)

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine#Generational_heap): The **permanent generation (or permgen)** was used for class definitions and associated metadata prior to Java 8. Permanent generation was not part of the heap.The permanent generation was removed from Java 8.

The JDK 8 HotSpot JVM is now using native memory for the representation of class metadata and is called [Metaspace](https://www.google.pl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Metaspace%20java); similar to the Oracle JRockit and IBM JVM's.